# Adding Background to Negative Axis of WPF Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a path that I am using to display a bar chart / line graph. The path has values on both positive and negative x values.  I would like to shade the negative x axis with either a red color or a slanted line.

How to add relative background to WPF Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shifted the negative axis to the right and calculated the new positioning.  This meant I had to do additional calculations to determine the real location at any given time, but it worked.